# Most general way to receive a functor as a parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a wrapper for a multithreaded scheme. It should operate similar to a timer.

I have a particular class (`clock`) that implements a function called `tick` which should be passed to constructor. How do I describe a C++ style function (myClass::myfunction, as opposed to the C convention) as the parameter to a method or constructor?

Would anybody be kind enough to show me the declaration for this kind of constructor?

```
clock myInstance(otherClass::aMethod)
myInstance.tick(); // Should call otherClass::aMethod
myInstance.tick();
```

Does C++11 and Bind help?

Comment: Are you asking how to pass a *non*-static *member* function of a C++ class as a parameter?

Comment: @WhozCraig, Yes, but it will not be virtual. If I can only use static, can you explain that in your answer?

Comment: What object should it call `otherClass::aMethod` on?

Comment: Without an object with which to provide a `this` context (virtual or not) you can only do it with a static class member, so you may wish to consider that as well.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you only want to accept `otherClass::aMethod` or any callable object?

Comment: You do know that is exactly as in C, right? Except, and you're aware of this already it seems, you must use the full function name, ie, MyClass::MyMethod...

Comment: I realize this violates the ToS, but I would like to point out that this question is quite naughty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either call a static member function of a class or a non-static member function of an object.  A non-static member function needs to have the context of an object (`this` pointer).

Here's a simplified example of how you can use functors and bind to call a member function.

```
#include <functional>

class clock
{
public:
   clock(const std::function<void()>& tocall) : m_tocall(tocall) {}
   void tick() {m_tocall();}

private:
   std::function<void()> m_tocall;
};

class otherclass
{
public:
   void aMethod() {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   otherclass A;
   clock c( std::bind(&otherclass::aMethod, &A) );

   c.tick(); // Will end up calling aMethod() of object A
}
```

Comment: Using a template argument instead of std::function would give you one less level of indirection and would speed up the call. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446596/c-boost-bind-performance/12446751

Comment: @slavik262 Thanks. I learnt something new :-)  If this isn't a performance bottleneck I'd choose the more readable form.  Since the member needs to be `std::function` unless you templatize the class I'm not sure there's any speed difference anyways?

Comment: `std::bind` does't return a `std::function` object - `bind`'s return value can just be *wrapped* by `function`, which does cause some overhead (see https://github.com/slavik262/function-indirection). But if this isn't performance-critical, feel free to use whatever you find more readable.

Comment: @slavik262: yeah I got that.  My point was if you use the return type of bind in the function what type is m_tocall.  If it's still a std::function then you need to do the conversion at that point.  Right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! You don't need to (and probably shouldn't) try to figure out what `bind` returns. Instead, you can make `clock` a class template (via `template<typename T> class clock` and then just use the template parameter as the type of `m_tocall` (i.e. `T m_tocall`). See the first SO thread I posted in the comments - you could then use `auto` to declare the lambda, and intantiate a `clock` with `clock<decltype(myLambda)> foo(myLambda);`

Answer (score 1):

You need not to use `std::function` for this. You need to have TWO pointers: One is the class-object, and one to the method of that class. In simple terms, you need to make it able to do:

```
CallNonVirtual(pClassPtr, pFuncAddr);
```

And therefore, you need both parameters, so that you can *actually* call it like:

```
(pClassPtr->*pFuncAddr)(); // Assuming no parameter
```

For this, you can do:

```
class Clock
{
    COtherClass* pClassPtr; 

    /// Typedef simplifies
    typedef void (COtherClass::*TargetFuncType)();
    TargetFuncType pFuncAddr;

public:
    Clock(COtherClass* pOther, TargetFuncType pFunc) : 
          pClassPtr(pOther), pFuncAddr(pFunc) 
   { 
   }

   void tick()
   {
       (pClassPtr->*pFuncAddr)();
   }
 };
```

And make a call:

```
int main()
{
   COtherClass Obj;
   Clock theClock(&Obj, &COtherClass::TheNonStatic);

   theClock.tick();
}
```